# GWT DevMode Options and Concepts

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-dev-mode

I just read the [GWT Guide for Compiling and Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging) and have several similarly-related questions:

1. What's an example use case for the `-whitelist` and `-blacklist` `DevMode` options and why are they not available for production mode?
2. Difference between `DevMode` and `HostedMode`? Use cases for both?
3. What sort of "extra" stuff happens when you specify the `-extra` flag?
4. What is `-workDir` and why must it be writeable? What gets written there? What can I use it for?
5. Is the embedded Jetty instance the same as the codeserver? If not, what is the difference?
6. Where does the "story of your compile" report (`soyc`) get generated and how to configure this location?

These questions are so closely-related I figured it would be better to ask them all up front rather than spam SO with 6 different micro-questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `-whitelist` and `-blacklist` are actually never used. They're a left over from the legacy *hosted mode* which embedded a browser widget (and could control the Same-Origin Policy), rather than being embedded in the browser through a plugin.
2. `HostedMode` is currently the same as `DevMode`. It only exists for backwards-compatibility (see above)
3. properties files for all your `Messages` and `Constants` for all your locales (provided you configured a [`@Generate`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.Generate.html) for those) to make it easier to bootstrap I18N, compile report –if you also pass `-compileReport`–, CSS maps of obfuscated `CssResource` class names, and logs of GWT-RPC serialization policies (which classes were included/excluded and why).
4. `-workDir` is where GWT writes most of it's temporary data (not all, some things go to the OS temporary folder –configurable with the `-Djava.io.tmpdir=` system property– or to a `.gwt-unitCache` folder –configurable with the `-Dgwt.persistentunitcachedir=` system property–). When you do [distributed builds](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DistributedBuilds), the `workDir` has to be shared by all machines (either shared on the network, or by copying files around).
5. In DevMode, the embedded Jetty server runs your webapp (your *server* code and your static resources) from the `-war` folder (defaults to `war/` in the current directory). The *codeserver* is what serves your *client* code. In DevMode, the *codeserver* uses a raw TCP connection to communicate with the plugin that sits in your browser; in SuperDevMode, the *codeserver* is a Jetty instance that serves JavaScript compiled (almost) *on the fly*, it doesn't host your webapp though.
6. See #3 above, and http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html

BTW, the GWT project now has a new home: http://www.gwtproject.org